# Programming Challenge: Reverse a string without using loops or native reversing functions

Tags: php, string, recursion, reverse

How would you write a short PHP function to reverse a string?

The function must:

- have only one argument,
- not use the built-in function `strrev()` or `array_reverse()`, and
- not use a looping construct like `for()`, `foreach()` or `while()`.

Comment: What about recursive functions? Or does that count as a loop?

Comment: @Benubird: Usually iterations (what loops are) are the opposite of recursions. I would bet, thats the goal of the homework ;)

Answer (score 13):

Quickly scanning down, these all look so long!

```
function rev($str) {
    return $str?rev(substr($str,1)).$str[0]:'';
}
```

Recursive so obviously doesn't work on strings longer than 100 chars.

Comment: To avoid tripping on a leading `0`, explicitly check for `strlen()`: `return strlen($str) ? (__FUNCTION__)(substr($str, 1)) . $str[0] : '';`

Answer (score 2):

Since this sounds like homework question I'll tell you how but you code it yourself.
Turn the string into an array with a cast. Then use one of the array sorting functions that takes a user defined sorting function.

Comment: isn't `uasort` a built-in function (wich shold be avoided) and just some kind of abstraction for a loop (wich should be avoided)? (but, in fact, without any kind of loop this would be almost impossible)

Comment: @oezi hmmmm, that got me thinking.

Comment: The question say not to use store or array_reverse. Not no built in functions at all. And yes usort is a looping abstraction but fills the question criteria of using no looping constructs.

Answer (score 2):

```
function reverseString($string) {
  return shell_exec(sprintf('ruby -e \'puts "%s".reverse\'', preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", $string)));
}
```

Comment: Not allowed using `strrev` in one language, so we take the same in another one? :D

Comment: I stand by my solution as valid in the letter of the rules, if not the spirit. :D

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution:

```
function sr( $txt ){
    return $txt[ strlen( $txt ) - 1 ] . ( ( strlen( $txt ) > 1 )?sr( substr( $txt, 0, strlen($txt)-1 ) ):null) ;
}

echo sr( "abc def ghi jklm" );
```

Explanation:

```
return $txt[ strlen( $txt ) - 1 ] // return last byte of string
.                                 // concatenate it with:
(( strlen( $txt ) > 1 ) ?         // if there are more bytes in string
 sr( substr( $txt, 0, strlen( $txt ) - 1 ) // then with reversed string without last letter
 : null );                        // otherwise with null
```

To make it work with zero-length string, another conditional expression was added:

```
return (strlen($txt))? ($txt[ strlen( $txt ) - 1 ] . ( ( strlen( $txt ) > 1 )?sr( substr( $txt, 0, strlen($txt)-1 ) ):null)):"" ;
```

Comment: Wow, heavy ^^ Can you format (and maybe describe) it. Would like to understand, would you are doing ;)

Comment: codaddict: you got me! `return (strlen($txt)>0)? ($txt[ strlen( $txt ) - 1 ] . ( ( strlen( $txt ) > 1 )?sr( substr( $txt, 0, strlen($txt)-1 ) ):null)):"" ;`

Comment: Actually, in the code-golf vein, you don't need the second if anymore: `return $txt? $txt[ strlen( $txt ) - 1 ] .sr( substr( $txt, 0, strlen($txt)-1 ) ) : "";` works just fine

Comment: Benubird: '0' casts to false :-)

Comment: `return strlen($str) ? $str[strlen($str) - 1] . (__FUNCTION__)(substr($str, 0, -1)) : '';`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    // Reversed string and Number
    //  For Example :
        $str = "hello world. This is john duvey";
        $number = 123456789;
        $newStr = strrev($str);
        $newBum = strrev($number);

        echo $newStr;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $newBum;

OUTPUT : 
 first : yevud nhoj si sihT .dlrow olleh
 second: 987654321`enter code here`
```

Comment: Question says: "_not use the built-in function 'strrev'_"

Answer (score 0):

Meets all your requirements but works only in PHP 5.3 or higher. Making it work on others is left as homework.

```
function reverse($str) {
        $i=0;
        $j=strlen($str)-1;
start:
        if($i>=$j) {
                goto done;
        }
        $tmp = $str[$j];
        $str[$j--] = $str[$i];
        $str[$i++] = $tmp;
        goto start;
done:
        return $str;
}
```

Comment: Writing a loop yourself is just the same like using a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverse_string($string) {
    if($string !== '')
        return substr($string, -1).reverse_string(substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-2));     
}
```

Comment: @mateusasza turned it to a recursive funtion

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution. Feels like something like that is what your teacher is looking for.

```
function my_strrev ($str) {
  $length = strlen($str);
  switch ($length) {
      case 0: return '';
      case 1: return $str; break;
      case 2: return $str[1] . $str[0];
      default :
          return $str[$length-1] .  my_strrev(substr($str,1,-1)) . $str[0];
          break;
  }
}
```

It swaps the first and the last letter and than makes the same with the rest of the string.

Update:
Inspired by mateusza I created another solution (its fun ;))

```
function my_strrev2 ($str) {
  return $str
    ? my_strrev2(substr($str, 1)) . $str[0]
    : '';
}
```

It works similar to mateuszas, but this one appends the first character, instead of prepend the last one.

Comment: `breaks` aren't necessary after `returns`. Also, an explicit `strlen()` check will not trip on a leading `0`: `return strlen($str) ? (__FUNCTION__)(substr($str, 1)) . $str[0] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP without using any function:

```
$String = "Hello World";

$i = 0;

// Find the end of the string
while (isset($String[$i])) {
    $i++;
}

// Decrement $i to point to the last character
$i--;


// Build the reversed string
while ($i >= 0) {
    $reversed .= $String[$i];
    $i--;
}

echo "Reversed :- $reversed"  ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Question says: "_not a use a looping construct like 'for', 'foreach' or 'while'._"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the string length limitations of recursion, you can use three steps with non-blacklisted functions.

1. Split into an array.
2. Sort by keys descending.
3. Implode the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eaSDn))

```
function revStr(string $str): string
{
    $str = str_split($str);
    krsort($str);
    return implode($str);
}

echo revStr('SnackOverflow');  // wolfrevOkcanS
```

As an IIFE:

```
echo (
      function($str) {
          $str = str_split($str);
          krsort($str);
          return implode($str);
      }
     )('SnackOverflow');
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is OOP and uses recursion. Takes care by itself of the recursion limit.

```
class StringReverser
{
    public $reversed_string;
    public function __construct ($string) {
        $original_recursion_limit = ini_get('pcre.recursion_limit');
        $array = str_split($string);
        krsort($array);
        $i = strlen($string);
        ini_set('pcre.recursion_limit', $i+1);
        $this->add2string($string, $i, $array);
        ini_set('pcre.recursion_limit', $original_recursion_limit);
    }

    public function reverse() {
        return $this->reversed_string;
    }

    private function add2string ($s, $i,  $a) {
        if($i) {
            $i--;
            $this->reversed_string .= $a[$i];
            $this->add2string($s, $i,$a, $this->reversed_string);
        }
    }
}


$string =  "Elzo Valugi";
echo $string ."<br>";
$reverser = new StringReverser($string);
echo $reverser->reverse();
```

Comment: care to explain the downvote? for a homework can be a better solution that a cryptic PERL like one liner.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 $string="jomon is name my";
 for($i=strlen($string);$i>=0;$i--)
 {
     $char.=$string{$i};    
 }
 echo $char."<br/>";

 for($i=0; $i<strlen($char);$i++)
 {
     if($char[$i+1]==" " || $char[$i+1]=="")
     {
         for($temp=$i; $temp>=0 && $char[$temp]!=' '; $temp--)
             echo $char[$temp];
     }
     echo " ";
 }    
 ?>
```

Comment: The OP wanted a solution *without using loops*